# Angular access a method inside a child component() v1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular v1.5 and changing from directives to component() and I'm facing a situation

I have this component hierarchy grandfather > father > grandson
and I'm trying to make a method available inside grandson component() so I'm passing the method from grandfather through grandson
but this doesn't work, someone can give me a clue? maybe show me what I'm doing wrong? :/

I put a bit of code here to explain what I'm doing: https://gist.github.com/WagnerMoreira/29ca7764eaa335784e06eccf8b0223cf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it can be done using `require` and, optional, `$onInit` like so:

```
require: {
    parent: '^nameOfParent'
}
```

Then in the controller that is making use of the inherited function you can initialize it like this:

```
vm.$onInit = init();

function init() {
    vm.foo = vm.parent.foo();
}
```

Comment: I need to use the require just on the grandson, and require the grandfather?